# Disallowing git merges into same upstream branch

Tags: git, merge

Is there a way to make a git repo reject attempts to push merge commits of a branch with an upstream version of that same branch? Basically I would like to prevent polluting the history with merges of the following general form:

Merge branch '*X*' of *remote* into *X*

Thus developers would need to either `pull --rebase` or manually stash-pull-pop stash-commit-push as described [here.](http://www.hitthebits.com/2013/04/extra-git-merge-commits.html) Other merge types (such as "Merge branch '*X*' into *Y*") should be still allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a server side to attempt to achieve this.

There are sample hooks in your repository in the repo/.git/hooks directory.

You can see a sample hook that parses a commit message here [on validating commit messages](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy)

Note that there are a handful of problematic cases with what you are trying to do however, and I have never personally come up with a solution that works in all cases.

Imagine Developer A does a "real" merge, and merges branch X into Y.

When they go to push however, they are rejected for non-fast-forward.  At this point, do you have them try a `git rebase -p` (which can be problematic), or have you instructed them to enable `git rerere` and to throw out the merge and redo it? Neither solution is as easy as just doing a `git merge` (typically).

I've had better luck forcing users to have `git config --global pull.rebase true` (or better, set it automatically somehow for them), which will make sure they are rebasing instead of merging.  Once you have that in place, you don't need to worry about the commit hook.